# Efficient implementation of string registration and look-up

Tags: matlab

I want to implement a recursive inner (helper) function that performs a standard depth-first traversal.  The function takes a string (of arbitrary length) as its first argument, and has this general structure:

```
function [] = helper(some_string, ...)

    if was_already_visited(some_string), return; end

    register_as_visited(some_string);

    % ... RECURSION on some_string ...

end
```

This strategy requires two additional (inner) functions, `was_already_visited` and `register_as_visited`, to ensure that the recursion does not fall into a cycle.

The `register_as_visited` function just keeps a record of all the arguments it has received to date.

The expression `was_already_visited(some_string)` evaluates to `true` if `register_as_visited(some_string)` has been executed before; or to `false` otherwise.

> I'm looking for a way to implement these two functions in MATLAB so that they are reasonably efficient.

---

FWIW, if were doing this in Python, my implementation of the above would be:

```
VISITED = set()  # a built-in container datatype


def was_already_visited(some_string):

    return some_string in VISITED


def register_as_visited(some_string):

    VISITED.add(some_string)


def helper(some_string, ...):

    if already_visited(some_string): return

    register_as_visited(some_string)

    # ... RECURSION on some_string ...
```

(Python's operations for adding an element to a `set` container and testing for membership in `set`'s are pretty efficient.)

Does MATLAB have something similar?

Comment: This should be possible using [set operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/set-operations.html) and cell arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think the simpliest option might be to use MALTAB class [containers.Map](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) - using your string as key associated with any value. Here is a brief overview:

Creation:

```
keys = {'string1', 'string2', 'string3'};

values = {true, true, true};

map = containers.Map(keys, values)
```

Add string

```
map('string4') = true;
```

Check if key is present

```
if map.isKey('string4') 
    ...
end
```